# Comment Symbol in Asymptote

Tags: texstudio, asymptote, comments

I use TeXStudio for text and Asymptote for making pictures. If I want to comment some part of the text I hit Ctrl+T and Ctrl+U to comment/uncomment (respectively) given selection. This inserts % symbols at the beginning of every single line of the selection. Works fine.

Asymptote has different style of the comment symbol, namely // - double slash. Very inconvenient IMHO.

How can I assign (not reassign, as I need the regular comment % symbol for text) any keyboard shortcut in TeXStudio for it to work in the same way as Ctrl+T and Ctrl+U but insert Asymtote's // backslash comment symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select `Asymptote` as highlighting, (un-)comment will insert/remove `//`

[image]